# Android: How to detect and collect multiple clicks (on multiple views) before batch processing

Tags: android, delay, detection

I have multiple Views that are clickable. I want to collect all the clicks in series if they're within 0.5 seconds of the previous click, then batch process the clicks only after 0.5 second of the very last click.

e.g.

```
Delay:     0.2    0.4    0.6
Click on A ---> B ---> C ---> D
```

Processing should be "ABC" (let's say passing them to the processing method as String "ABC" will do), then another process for "D". I'm having problem coming up with the "wait-and-see" part. What is a good approach to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: its preety easy show us what you have tried??

Comment: I haven't tried out any code yet. Still in the thinking phase. It feels like some kind of timer-resetting thread is in order and if it runs to the end, then process whatever it has on hand. Question with this approach are:how can I check if the thread already exists in the first place, so that I don't create one with each click?

Comment: its better to do some work first then ask for solutions

Comment: OK. Let me try and come back later.

Comment: @IllegalArgument - Please take a look at my approach. They seem ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing it via Handler which is quite simple for this case. For those who are interested, I defined a handler in the activity that handles a designated message which is to process something immediately. Then on every click, I clear the message queue and then send a message with that 0.5sec delay.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 3001:
            process();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

and whenever there's a View that I'm interested in, I add the following lines in its onClickListener()

```
myHandler.removeMessages(3001);
myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(3001, 500);
```

There may be a case of over-removing msg3001 but that's ok as it's being handled by the system gracefully.

Comment: Cannot accept own answer until after 48 hours... will do so.